# How to disable pause() in game_loop() once game_over() function is called?

Tags: architecture, game-loop, pygame, logic, game-state

How can I disable pause()  in  game_loop()  once  game_over() function is called?

## game loop

```
def game_loop():
    global playerX, playerY, playerX_change, playerY_change, bulletX, bulletY, bulletY_change, bullet_state
    global score

    # background music
    mixer.music.load('bg music.mp3')
    mixer.music.play(-1)

    running = True

    while running:

        # set background image(bg)
        bg = pygame.image.load('bg 2.PNG')
        screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    pause()
                    game_loop()

            # movement of player L, R , U & D
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    playerX_change -= 7

                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    playerX_change += 7

                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    playerY_change -= 7

                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    playerY_change += 7

                # update bullet position when shift in player position + bullet sound
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    if bullet_state == "ready":
                        bullet_sound = mixer.Sound('bullet.wav')
                        bullet_sound.play()
                        bulletX = playerX
                        fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    playerX_change = 0

                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    playerY_change = 0

        playerX += playerX_change
        # for player stay inside game window (L & R)
        if playerX >= 650:  # R
            playerX = 650
        elif playerX <= 20:  # L
            playerX = 20

        playerY += playerY_change
        # for player stay inside game window (U & D)
        if playerY >= 370:  # D
            playerY = 370
        if playerY <= 350:  # U
            playerY = 350

        # for enemies to stay inside game window & enemies movement
        for i in range(no_of_enemies):
            # game over
            if enemyY[i] >= 340:
                for j in range(no_of_enemies):
                    enemyY[j] = 1000
                game_over()
                break

            enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
            if enemyX[i] >= 720:  # R
                enemyX_change[i] -= 5
                enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
            elif enemyX[i] <= 20:  # L
                enemyX_change[i] += 5
                enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]

            # collision for every enemy
            result = collision(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], bulletX, bulletY)
            if result:
                enemy_to_blast(enemyX[i], enemyY[i])
                explosion_sound = mixer.Sound('explosion.wav')
                explosion_sound.play()
                score += 1
                bulletY = 445
                bullet_state = "ready"
                enemyX[i] = random.randint(20, 720)
                enemyY[i] = random.randint(20, 150)

            # call enemy func
            enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)

        # bullet movement
        if bullet_state == "fire":
            fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
            bulletY -= bulletY_change
            # re-appearance of bullet at start point
            if bulletY <= 0:  # U
                bulletY = 445
                bullet_state = "ready"

        # call funcs 'player' & 'score'
        player(playerX, playerY)
        display_score()
        display_pause()

        pygame.display.update()
```

## pause()

```
def pause():
    global running

    # background music for paused screen
    mixer.music.load('start.mp3')
    mixer.music.play(-1)

    paused = True

    while paused:

        txt_on_screen(paused_text_font_1, "PROJECT ANNIHILATION", 0, (-120), white, black)
        txt_on_screen(paused_text_font_2, "0N HOLD", 0, (-70), red, black)
        txt_on_screen(paused_text_font_3, " RESUME >> esc ", 0, 0, black, light_purple)
        txt_on_screen(start_text_font_3, " SETTINGS >> s ", 0, 50, black, light_purple)
        txt_on_screen(start_text_font_4, " QUIT >> Delete ", 0, 100, black, light_purple)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                paused, running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:  # RESUME GAME
                    paused = False
                    mixer.music.stop()
                    break
                if event.key == pygame.K_DELETE:
                    paused, running = False
                # if event.type == pygame.K_s >>>>> volume settings
        pygame.display.update()
```

## game over

```
def game_over():
    global bullet_state
    # centering game-over text
    txt_on_screen(game_over_font, "GAME-OVER!", 0, 0, light_purple, None)
    # centering game-over 'instructions' text
    txt_on_screen(below_txt_font, "Press 'Delete' to QUIT, 'r' to RESTART", 0, 50, white, black)

    # game-over sound effect
    end_sound = mixer.Sound('end.wav')
    end_sound.play()
    mixer.music.set_volume(0)

    # unable shooting bullets
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bullet_state = "ready"
            if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                game_loop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `game_over()` inside `game_loop()`, and `game_loop()` again inside `game_over()`, and I *think* that could eventually reach an OverFlowError if you restart the game too many times (though I am not 100% sure).

What if you did something similar to `pause()` and write a while loop inside the `game_over()` function that leads you back to `game_loop()` once it's over? That way you would also disable `pause()` from being called.

e.g.

````python
def game_over():
    global bullet_state
    # centering game-over text
    txt_on_screen(game_over_font, "GAME-OVER!", 0, 0, light_purple, None)
    # centering game-over 'instructions' text
    txt_on_screen(below_txt_font, "Press 'Delete' to QUIT, 'r' to RESTART", 0, 50, white, black)

    # game-over sound effect
    end_sound = mixer.Sound('end.wav')
    end_sound.play()
    mixer.music.set_volume(0)

    game_over = True
    while game_over:
        # unable shooting bullets
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    bullet_state = "ready"
                if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    game_over = False

```
````